# Identificar fieldset

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un formulario que esta formado por fieldsets donde hay inputs de text etc, mi pregunta es como puedo saber en que `fieldset` estoy y así poder guardar la información de los inputs del `fieldset` actual.
Todo esto desde mi `onload=page()` de mi body.

```html
<Form>
        <fieldset id="field1">
            ...
            <input type="button" name="password" class="next btn btn-info" value="Next" onclick="next()" />
                   
        </fieldset>
        
        <fieldset id="field2">
            ...
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-default" value="Previous" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
        
        <fieldset id="field3">
            ...
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-default" value="Previous" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
        
</Form>
```

```
Function page()
{
 ..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el atributo [`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName) para obtener el *tipo* de un determinado elemento (contiene el nombre del tipo, en MAYÚSCULAS). Combinado con [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) (para obtener el nodo padre), permite obtener lo que buscas.

Con eso, ya solo es cuestión de *engancharnos* donde necesitemos:

```js
document.addEventListener( "click", function( e ) {    
    var item = e.target.parentNode;

    if( item.nodeName && ( item.nodeName == 'FIELDSET' ) ) {
        document.getElementById( 'ITEM' ).innerHTML = item.id;
    }
} );
```

```html
<Form>
        <p id="ITEM"> --- </p>
        <fieldset id="field1">
            <input type="button" name="password" class="next btn btn-info" value="Next"/>
        </fieldset>
        
        <fieldset id="field2">
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-default" value="Previous" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="Next"/>
        </fieldset>
        
        <fieldset id="field3">
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-default" value="Previous"/>
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="Next"/>
        </fieldset>
</Form>
```